# FormsAuthenticationTicket.Version returns invalid version number

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, forms-authentication

Is there any limit on the size/numbers in the version number of the FormsAuthenticationTicket.

I tried to create an ASP.NET cookie using forms authentication, with a large version number(ex: 1234567 need this number for identification purposes). But when I decrypt the cookie I get 135 as the version number.

Initially the old forms authentication cookie was removed, in order to add new information.

```
Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
```

Following is the code I used to create the FormsAuthentication cookie.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1234567, un, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(5F), false, user_data);
HttpCookie newauthCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newAuthTicket));

Response.Cookies.Add(newauthCookie);
```

After retrieving the cookie, the version number I got was 135. This number varies with different version numbers.

```
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

if (authCookie == null)
{
    return;
}

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTkt = null;
authTkt = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

if (authTkt == null)
{
    return;
}
int versionID = authTkt.Version;
```

Can someone let me know if it's a bad idea to use such big version numbers, or am I missing something in this.

Thanks for your help,
Vijay

Comment: Why are you storing identification information in the verion? Couldn't you do the same with the `UserData`?

Comment: You also posted at: http://forums.asp.net/p/1661433/4334634.aspx/1?Re+FormsAuthenticationTicket+Version+returns+invalid+version+number

Comment: @Daniel: I've other user data that is stored in the UserData part of the cookie. But I still don't understand why the value is changed when the VersionID property should be able to take an Int value. 
Yes I did post it in the asp.net forum hoping for different suggestions. :)

Comment: Why can't you put it in userdata?

Comment: To make things complicated my last option would be storing the identification info in the user data with other additional user data. But what's the reason for the changed value of the version number when decrypted? Is it a known bug?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be a limitation of the encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the ticket name is not passed as null.

Comment: The ticket name has a value for sure.